# Problems with for loops in python

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

In a code for rock, paper, scissor I have two variables: `choose` for storing the user's choice of rock, paper, scissors and `pc_move` to randomly choose one of them and store them as r,p and s.
For eg, if user opts for rock,

```
choose = 'r'
```

I want this to be printed as a separate line as:

```
print(f'{name} chooses {choose}')
```

So i use this nested loop to achieve this purpose:

```
for tag in [choose,pc_move]:
        if tag == 'r':
            tag = 'rock'
        elif tag == 's':
            tag = 'scissor'
        elif tag == 'p':
            tag = 'paper'
```

If `choose` is rock it is stored as 'r' and I want it to change to 'rock'. The same goes for `pc_move`. But I can't see the changes in the output.
What is the mistake am I doing? I don't know much about python, I'm a rookie. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `choose` is a verb. Verbs make good methods. Nouns make good objects, so `choice` is probably a better variable name

Comment: ``tag`` is just a name. It does not "know" that its assigned value comes from either ``choose`` or ``pc_move``, and especially not that it should update these two on being reassigned.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if ```choose``` and ```pc_move``` don't get updated, then is not possible to do it by using the for loop? I just want to know for the sake of using the for loop.

Comment: It is not possible to use a for loop for this. Names are not [first-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), the ``for`` loop cannot operate on them (it immediately operates on their *values*).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop; you just need two separate calls to `print`, along with a `dict` that maps tags to moves.

```
d = {'r': 'rock', 's': 'scissor', 'p': 'paper'}

print(f'Computer chooses {d[pc_move]}')
print(f'{name} chooses {d[choose]}')
```

Comment: This is a very nice way of doing the question! But can you please point out the mistake in the code I wrote? Is it not possible by the way I did?

Comment: You didn't show enough to do anything. You reset `tag`, but didn't have a `print` statement in the for loop to *use* the new tag.